# How to Subdivide into equal squares on a "Triangular" face

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode, subdivision-surface

I'm making this model and I want to subdivide one of my faces into equal squares on a triangular shape. When I try to subdivide it, it gets subdivided according to how many faces there are (in this case, triangles). Does anyone know how I could go about this? Photo for what I mean:[image]

Comment: use knife tool by pressing K!

Comment: Well yes technically I could subdivide the face evenly, but thats a lot of manual work. Not to mention tedious with the amount of subdividing I would have to do. Do you know any other way of going about this?

Comment: I think there is no direct option for traingular cuts, if you want more loop cuts at once, press Ctrl + R and then scroll middle mouse button so that the amount of loop cuts increase. But this will make square loop cuts!